# GAE app went over quota "Incoming Bandwidth" after serving only 3 requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a low traffic site at https://paperlink2.appspot.com

I enabled the billing over the weekend to tweak the datastore. When it was done, I disabled the billing.

Yesterday, just after the midnight, I notice my "Incoming Bandwidth" was over quota.

Since the over quota happened right at the midnight, I paid close attention today - and it went off after serving only 3 requests... 9 kb... in 3 minutes...

How could that happen?
If anyone in the GAE team could have a quick look, I really appreciate~~
Could anyone please give any suggestion? Thanks!

Below is today's log

```
----------------------------
2012-07-31 00:04:28.071 /js?y=0.29361433181115804 503 100ms 0kb
213.112.244.168 - - [31/Jul/2012:00:04:28 -0700] "GET /js?y=0.29361433181115804 HTTP/1.1" 503 0 - - "paperlink2.appspot.com" ms=100 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000040 

 2012-07-31 00:03:48.053 /js?y=0.4865090114862315 200 68ms 3kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
213.112.244.168 - - [31/Jul/2012:00:03:48 -0700] "GET /js?y=0.4865090114862315 HTTP/1.1" 200 3874 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1" "paperlink2.appspot.com" ms=69 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000473 instance=00c61b117c8c6f5d69c0df046a884b741337aa

2012-07-31 00:03:28.231 /js?y=0.5931225973034153 200 188ms 3kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
213.112.244.168 - - [31/Jul/2012:00:03:28 -0700] "GET /js?y=0.5931225973034153 HTTP/1.1" 200 3874 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1" "paperlink2.appspot.com" ms=188 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000477 instance=00c61b117c8c6f5d69c0df046a884b741337aa

2012-07-31 00:03:19.859 /js?y=0.5153093388288915 200 4576ms 3kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
213.112.244.168 - - [31/Jul/2012:00:03:19 -0700] "GET /js?y=0.5153093388288915 HTTP/1.1" 200 3874 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1" "paperlink2.appspot.com" ms=4576 cpu_ms=957 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.027121 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c8c6f5d69c0df046a884b741337aa

I2012-07-31 00:03:19.859
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.


2012-07-30 23:59:35.503 / 503 56ms 0kb
165.225.134.101 - - [30/Jul/2012:23:59:35 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 0 - - "paperlink2.appspot.com" ms=56 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000020 
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Few notes:

1. Which timezone do you mean by "midnight"? Afaik GAE billing day is PST.
2. 9kb you are referring to is outgoing bandwidth.
3. When a resource is depleted, GAE will produce 403 error. I see nu such error in the log you provided.

Comment: I am in California. "Midnight" = 0 PST

Comment: 3 requests each had 3 kb outgoing bandwidth. You are correct that I do not have a place to check inbound bandwidth. However, the code didn't change and the app was running fine~~

Comment: I setup the error_handlers. Those /js URL should give 200, but was giving 503 after 3 requests. Thanks